Kafka not appear in cluster
I deployed a Kafka cluster using Helm with Strimzi charts. However, only Zookeeper pods were created in the cluster, and Kafka pods were not found.

Here is my yaml file:
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.7.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        tls: false
        type: nodeport
        configuration:
          brokers:
            - broker: 0
              advertisedHost: localhost
              advertisedPort: 31769
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.7"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    jvmOptions: #4
      javaSystemProperties:
        - name: zookeeper.ssl.hostnameVerification
          value: 'false'
        - name: zookeeper.ssl.quorum.hostnameVerification
          value: 'false'
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 2Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}

Here is the event logs from Kubenete

I have tried to fix it, but I was unsuccessful.
